# How to fix lifetime error due to RFC 1214

Tags: rust, lifetime

Consider the following code:

```
pub fn use_r<I, R>(xs: I, r: &R) {
    unimplemented!()
}

fn test<'a, R>(r: &'a mut R) {
    let a = |r: &'a mut R| {
        [(|| use_r(vec![0.].into_iter(), r))()]
    };
    a(r);
    // a(r);
}

fn test2<R>(r: &mut R) {
    let a = |r: &mut R| {
        [(|| use_r(vec![0.].into_iter(), r))()]
    };
    a(r);
    a(r);
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=54602110bdc2fc027dbd&version=stable)

`test` compiles with the latest `nightly`, but I cannot call `a(r);` twice. `test2` compiles with `stable` and does what I want, but it does not compile on `nightly`.

The motivation is that I have a RNG which I want to pass into an internal closure a few different times. What do I need to do to allow `test2` to compile?

Comment: if you use just `|r|` it compiles.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the compiler doesn't accept your `test2` function. It compiles fine if you eliminate the unnecessary nested lambda:

```
fn test2<R>(r: &mut R) {
    let a = |r: &mut R| {
        [use_r(vec![0.].into_iter(), r)]
    };
    a(r);
    a(r);
}
```

I also found that the compiler accepts the code if you use a shared reference with explicit lifetime:

```
fn test2<'a, R>(r: &'a mut R) {
    let a = |r: &'a R| {
        [(|| use_r(vec![0.].into_iter(), r))()]
    };
    a(r);
    a(r);
}
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't work with a `&mut` reference, or why the compiler can't infer the lifetime automatically.

Do you really have an unnecessary (immediately invoked) nested lambda? I suspect you simplified the code too much and are asking a different question than you meant to ask.

Comment: Yes, I do in fact have a nested lambda that I immediately invoke :(. The reason is that I want to pass a code fragment to a inlining macro, which works by calling the lambda.